# Extracting text between HTML tags using perl

Tags: html, perl

I have HTML tags in a document as follows:

```
><H2 
align="justify"
><FONT size="+2" color="#008AD9"><B>ACCESS_NUMBER<FONT size="+2" color="#008AD9"><B>
</H2
>
```

I want to  extract only ACCESS_NUMBER from the above HTML text.

How can I do this? I want to make sure only the text between all `<H2>` tags is extracted.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried?  Also is this **literally** how the code appears (*i.e* with `<` strangely wrapped) in the document, or did you improperly format the code section of your question?  I did a bit of editing to make it all appear but otherwise left it as it was. The format of the code would effect a regular expression.

Comment: A parser might be able to extract the text you want if the document is consistent with some definition of "HTML" :-)

Answer (score 4):

Use [**Mojo::DOM**](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo%3a%3aDOM)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Mojo::DOM;
my $HTML = <<"EOF";
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>
<font><b>ACCESS_NUMBER</b></font> 
</h2>
</body>
</html>
EOF

my $dom = Mojo::DOM->new( $HTML );
print $dom->find('h2 font b')->text;
```

For a 8 minute video tutorial on `Mojo::DOM` and `Mojo::UserAgent` check out [`Mojocast Episode 5`](http://mojocasts.com/e5)

Comment: Upvoted. 99.9% of the time it's much better to use a proper HTML parser like this method than a regex.

Comment: Exactly my thoughts ... and I was going to suggest `Mojo::DOM` :-)

Comment: Thank you for passing on the `Mojo::DOM` love while including the video.  They really should add that to the pod. +1

Comment: They should make more videos.

Answer (score 1):

Based on what's given above, this will work, but something tells me you have more complicated HTML and/or you actually want \d+.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

while(<DATA>){
    print "$1\n" if />(\w+)</;
}

__DATA__
<H2
   align="justify"
  <FONT size="+2" color="#008AD9"><B>ACCESS_NUMBER<FONT size="+2" color="#008AD9"><B>S
  </H2
```

Answer (score 0):

## For each line remove html tags like this:

```
$l=~s/<.+?>/ /g; # Replace each tag with a space so you don't get run-on words.
```

What you're left with is only text with no html tags.

I use software that uses tags (not html) which I have to remove, so I do this a lot.